# How to get geoLocation in BIRT report

Tags: java, eclipse, report, birt

I am using BIRT reporting tool  for generating report.I have requirement to show geo location name corresponding to longitude and latitude.In report i want display,corresponding geo location name(ie:using Google map API's) in a table.I dont need to display google map.How can i do this in BIRT report.

Answer (score 3):

You can insert the jsfiddle you mentionned as it is in a birt text element, see a live example of google API embedded in a BIRT report [here](http://www.visioneo.org/google-map).

Though it is important to note it makes use of a **client-side** geocoding API, whereas usual BIRT scripts are **server-side** javascripts. This implies limitations:

To introduce a client-side javascript in BIRT, we have to:

- Insert a BIRT text element in the report
- Set the type to "HTML" in the dropdown at the top of the element
- Insert the HTML markup & Javascript code as text content

That's quite easy, but when we get a such content through a client-side javascript, it won't be available for exports PDF, Powerpoint etc: it only appears in HTML format.

In order to make it available for other formats such PDF, we have to use a **java** geocoder API such [google's](https://code.google.com/p/geocoder-java/), and provide relevant "jar" libraries to the BIRT engine as explained [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/BIRT/FAQ/Scripting#Q%3a_Where_do_I_have_to_put_my_classes_in_order_to_access_them_by_JavaScript.3F).

Some geocoding java API are free and/or open source but the geocoding services might be limited. Read carefully the terms of use.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is possible to call external java package from report generated by BIRT tool, so, my thinking is you may write a java method to call [google geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding)(which could resolve the geo location name from longitude and latitude), then call the java method from report.

Comment: i am new to birt.i dont know how can i achieve..can u pls share any sample report

Comment: or is it possible in javascript level itsef??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/LSMXQ/  ..is it possible to implement this in birt

Comment: Saying, you have a java class Geo which has a static method resolveGeoName and located in com.test, then if you want to invoke this method, all you have to do is to add importPackage( Packages.com.test ) statement to your report script, then call Geo.resolveGeoName from your report script. About report script,you can refer to [BIRT official doc](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/deploy/reportScripting.php).

Comment: I didn't try it in javascript level before, you can take a shot and remember to tell me the result :P